# Change the default countdown for tasks based on a certain task class?

Tags: celery

I have a custom celery task class that then I use in the decorator @celeryApp.task. I execute the tasks with apply_async.

My task class is:

```
class CeleryTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        pass

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        pass
```

Then I declare my tasks like:

```
@celeryApp.task(base=CeleryTask)
def my_celery_task(param1, param2):
    pass
```

And finally I execute it with apply_async

```
my_celery_task.apply_async(
        (
            'value1', 'value2'
        ),
        countdown=2)
```

I would like to have all tasks based on CeleryTask to have a count down of 2.

However I don't see anywhere in the documentation how to do it. I had a look at celery.app.task:Task but there is no countdown property.

Is there anyway to have a default countdown for certain task classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, the Task class does not hold the countdown property. I think that is so mainly because the countdown is something that describes HOW the task is executed - it is not something that describes the task itself.

However, that is not the end of the world. You have a pretty good solution for this.

- Implement your Task subclass that *does* have the "countdown" property.
- Override all the methods that take "countdown" as parameter. Their implementation is trivial as they will call superclass methods, with `coundown=self.m_countdown` (or however you named it).